# algorithm of calculating the slope between line relatively to center coordinate

Tags: geometry, atan2

Please help with the algorithm of calculating the slope
So we have a Cartesian coordinate system. X right at Y the top. There is a line which passes through the center of coordinates.
Needed to determine the angle relatively to the axis OX.

So here's what I'm doing

1. Certain functions transferred to the origin (top line) and end of line
2. Determine dx, dy
3. Hildren releases two parameters in atan2 (dy, dx)
4. Returns the result in radians.

But! I atan2 works only within 180 degrees. After 180 goes in another direction.

**So the question: what is the correct algorithm for finding the angle? Do I need to take dy, dx values in magnitude? How to make the arctangent calculated for all 360 and more? I would be glad to hear specific algorithms, or pieces of code comments.
Thanx!**

```
static inline CGFloat angleBetweenLinesInRadians2 (CGPoint line1Start, CGPoint line1End)
{
CGFloat dx = 0, dy = 0;

dx = line1End.x - line1Start.x; / / whether to do fabs (line1End.x - line1Start.x);
dy = line1End.y - line1Start.y;

CGFloat rads = atan2 (dy, dx); / / whether to do fabs (rads)

return rads;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

atan2() is supposed to return a value in the interval [-pi,pi] (i.e. [-180, 180] ), and works with the signs of x and y to figure out the quadrant. ([C++ ref](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/atan2/))

So technically, you have 360 degrees.

Comment: So the question: what is the correct algorithm for finding the angle? Do I need to take dy, dx values in magnitude?

Comment: Don't use magnitude - just use dy and dw with the correct signs, and atan2() will return the correct angle value. If you want all your angles in positive values (i.e. convert from [-180,180] to [0,360]), just leave the positive values unchanged, and add 360 to the negative values. For instance, -90° will give 270°.

Comment: sorry, I mean do I need to calculate absolute value of dx, dy?

Comment: dy = fabs(line1End.y - line1Start.y)

Comment: No, you should not, as atan2() uses the sign of dy and dx to give you the correct angle value.

Comment: if (rads < 0)
 {
  rads += (2*3.14);
 }

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was saying before :)

Answer (score 0):

A formula to calculate an angle from 0 to 360 degrees :

f(x,y)=180-90*(1+sign(x))* (1-sign(y^2))-45*(2+sign(x))*sign(y)

```
    -180/pi()*sign(x*y)*atan((abs(x)-abs(y))/(abs(x)+abs(y)))

    x=x2-x1 and y=y2-y1 .
```